# IIS, asp.net deployment

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am running two application on a single application pool. for one of the application my local database gets connected but for the other I get following error

The login failed.
Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0'.

Answer (score 0):

Just set same account in both services.

For example:

1. Open sql server configuration manager -> sql server -> properties -> built-in account: set "Local Service"
2. Open IIS manager -> app pools -> .NET v5 -> advanced settings ->
   Identity -> built-in account: set "Local Service"

Answer (score 0):

Adding "IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0" user in SQL will work. For Example.
 1) In SQL Server > Security > Login - Right Click > New Login
 2) Add the above user. 
 3) Grant the permissions to the specific Database